# AES CBC encryption: does it make sense if I expose the IV along with encryption result (just for conveniently getting IV when decrypt)?

Tags: encryption

I have seen some code piece (for example, in Ruby)

```
require 'openssl'

def encrypt_aes_256_cbc(plain_text, encrypt_key)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)
  cipher.encrypt
  iv = cipher.random_iv
  cipher.key = encrypt_key.ljust(cipher.key_len, '\0').slice(0, 32)
  encrypted = cipher.update(plain_text) + cipher.final
  (encrypted + iv).unpack('H*').first
end

def decrypt_aes_256_cbc(encrypted_text, encrypt_key)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)
  cipher.decrypt
  raw_data = [encrypted_text].pack('H*')
  cipher.iv = raw_data.slice(raw_data.length - 16, 16)
  cipher.key = encrypt_key.ljust(cipher.key_len, '\0').slice(0, 32)
  cipher.update(raw_data.slice(0, raw_data.length - 16)) + cipher.final
end
```

This encryption exposes IV to the result,
suppose a hacker gets the result of `encrypt_aes_256_cbc`, then he gets the IV,
does this mean that the CBC mode become non sense?

Is this implementation OK?

Comment: Without commenting on whether the implementation is OK, the question of whether IV must be secret or not has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40981507/1277259), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704398/1277259) for example. In essence, the IV need not be kept secret (unlike the key).

Comment: this is exactly what I want to know. Thank you so much.